# Can I use a fuse tap with an external fuse on the power cable?

Tags: wiring, fuse, fuse-panel

I have a power cable for an active underseat subwoofer that I want to attach to my fusebox (corsa d 2008).

My plan is to take out a non-important 15A fuse, put it on the fuse tap in the bottom slot and leave the top slot open as my power cable has a fuse on it. Would this work?

Tap:

[image: fuse tap]

The blue fuse would be empty and the slot below would be my stock fuse I took out. The red cable has a fuse attached to it.

Extra question: it's a small subwoofer (Kenwood KSC-SW11), is it ok to attach this to my glove box fuse box? From what I've heard it only pulls like 7.5A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the top slot open (no fuse) creates an open circuit from the fuse tap hot lead to the aux lead that is created by the device. Consider that power travels from the left side of the U-shaped piece of metal in the photo, travels to the left side of the fuse sockets (both of them) and stops.

The fuse inserted in the bottom allows electricity to return to the fuse block through the factory fuse.

The fuse inserted in the top allows electricity to travel to the red wire. No fuse, no electricity.

Your second question should be presented in a second post.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how they work now. Can I add a fuse to the top then while using a power cable that also has a fuse? I'm sure it will work but I'm not sure about the safety?

Comment: If you have two fuses in a circuit, it is likely that the fuse with the lower value will blow before the higher value fuse. If they are the same, it will depend on manufacturing tolerance and accuracy of the fuse values.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll get an extra fuse for the top then and run 2 fuses in the circuit. I don't expect them to blow haha. You were a big help so thank you.